# CLion Unknown Module Type Error

Tags: clion

I have a simple project that confuses CLion. Whenever I open the project Clion reports:

Unknown Module Type
           Cannot determine module type ("CIDR_MODULE") for the following module:"gluecpp"
           The module will be treated as a Unknown module.

I can build the project through CLion, but syntax highlighting is crippled (only keywords, operators and strings are recognized), and it no longer highlights files in the project tab based on their status (e.g. is referenced in the CMakeLists.txt, etc.)

I am using CLion 1.1.1 on OS X 10.10.5

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Delete the ".idea/" in your project folder and then reopen your project, you'll be glad to find everything works fine.

Carefully backup your project settings, because you gonna lose them if you really do this.

Comment: Please note that _ALL_ your preferences from your IDE will then be deleted.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: Works for CLion 2017.1